# GATconv dimensions

Tags: python, pytorch, dgl

When I use this class to build a GATConv network to predict the class of a graph I get a dimension error. How would I resolve this.

```py
class GraphClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_feats, hidden_size, num_classes):
        super(GraphClassifier, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = GATv2Conv(in_feats, hidden_size, num_heads=4)
        self.conv2 = GATv2Conv(4*hidden_size, hidden_size, num_heads=4)
        self.conv3 = GATv2Conv(4*hidden_size, hidden_size, num_heads=4)
        self.conv4 = GATv2Conv(4*hidden_size, hidden_size, num_heads=1)
        self.classify = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.5)
        
    def forward(self, g, inputs):
        h = self.conv1(g, inputs)
        h = F.elu(h)
        h = self.dropout(h)
        
        h = self.conv2(g, h)
        h = F.elu(h)
        h = self.dropout(h)
        
        h = self.conv3(g, h)
        h = F.elu(h)
        h = self.dropout(h)
        
        h = self.conv4(g, h)
        h = F.elu(h)
        h = self.dropout(h)
        
        with g.local_scope():
            g.ndata['h'] = h
            # Calculate graph representation by max pooling readout.
            hg = dgl.max_nodes(g, 'h')
            return self.classify(hg)
```

This is the code used for training:

```py
import torch.nn.functional as F
model = GraphClassifier(dataset.dim_nfeats, 16, dataset.gclasses)
        
opt = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01, weight_decay=1e-4)
# Instantiate a predefined optimizer from torch.optim - this 
      # is the method that will be used to perform Gradient Descent.
      # We recommend using Adam.

for epoch in range(400):
    
    model.train()               # Set the model to train mode to allow gradients to be calculated
    
    cumulative_loss_train = 0.0 # Use this accumulate loss over an epoch and print it out at the end
                                # to get an estimate for how well your model is performing
    
    for batched_graph, labels in trainloader:
        features = batched_graph.ndata['attr']
        
        logits = model(batched_graph, batched_graph.ndata["attr"])
                       
        loss = F.cross_entropy(logits, labels) # Compute cross entropy loss. 
        
        opt.zero_grad()         # Reset gradients for the next batch, since they accumulate by default
        loss.backward()         # Backprop
        opt.step()         # Update parameters
        
        cumulative_loss_train += loss.item()
```

This is the error message:
RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (7140x16 and 64x64)
The error refers to this line: h = self.conv2(g, h) in the forward function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `h = self.conv1(g, inputs)`, the dims of h is: `[node_num, num_heads, hidden_size]`, so you can reshape h by

```
h = h.reshape(h.shape[0], -1)
h = self.conv2(g, h)
```